# Firemonkey: TLabel text truncated despite autosize property true

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

I am coming across a strange issue with my Firemonkey application.  Here is a screenshot of my application when run on my local Windows 8.1 machine.  Inside the blue panel, is an auto sizing label with a purposely long description to make sure the sizing is working.

[image]

Everything seems fine, until I run the same application on a particular remote machine.  Here is a screenshot of the same application, running on a remote Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

[image]

As you can see, the label inside of the blue panel is now being truncated, despite its auto size property being set to true.  Additionally, the "Show Logs" button has it's text truncated as well.

In addition to verifying the auto size property of the label, I have tried running the remote machine at different window sizes to see if the issue had something to do with screen resolution.  However, the label continued to be truncated.

Does Firemonkey have any known issues with drawing things differently across different operating systems?  Are there any display settings on the remote machine that could cause the application to render incorrectly?  Anything else I should looks at to try and narrow down / resolve the issue?

Comment: Fonts render differently on different systems, and that might explain the button's text issue. The button actually looks a different size in the two screen caps, but I don't know if that's an artifact of the screen cap, different monitor resolution, or what.

Comment: Possible workaround: instead of using autosize, set it to a fixed length which is the maximum allowable length, and then make sure it's left-aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering around with a bunch of settings both in XE8 and on Windows I finally found the solution.  The machine running Windows Server 2008 R2 had all of its visual enhancement settings turned off which caused the application to render in correctly.

The specific setting which needed to be enabled was "Use Visual Styles on Windows and Buttons".  It appears this setting has to do with Aero as it is not available on my Windows 8.1 machine.

To get to this setting, navigate to:

`Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced Tab -> Settings Button in Performance Panel -> Visual Effects Tab -> Check "Use Visual Styles on Windows and Buttons"`

[image]

With this setting enabled, I was able to get my application to render correctly.  Additionally, I was able to replicate the problem on other machines by manipulating this setting.

Answer (score 0):

By default, TLabel is set to WordWrap = True. Try setting it to false. I had a similar problem on mobile devices and turning WordWrap off fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Looks like word wrap was already set to false in my case.

Comment: Yes. As it turns out, setting Autosize = true automatically sets WordWrap = false. I now remember, my issue was with Alignment + WordWrap, not Autosize + WordWrap.